Adding metadata of specific layer as legend to map in ArcGIS Pro
I have multiple feature layers, each associated with specific properties. I have added these properties as descriptions in the metadata of each layer.
I would like to know if it is possible to display the "description" section from the metadata of a feature layer as a table on the map.
I also attempted to create a separate table but couldn't figure out how to link it to the feature layer.
Is there a way to automate this process?
All I need is to display the properties as a table in the map using a simple click.

https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/arcpy/metadata/metadata-class.htm

Dynamic text can pull from layout and map metadata but not a feature. Would be best to have a properties database table with features and properties, can be dynamic based on map series.
